# Would it be possible to remove or hide values from Grafana dashboard when data coming from blackbox_exporter has probe_success = 0?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I am trying to monitor some IP addresses locally with [blackbox_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) through Prometheus and Grafana for visualization.

I am able to gather the data I need with ICMP pings but if they fail I get the timeout time as ping duration (as per design) instead of null (or empty).

I did verify that in the event of an unsuccessful ping the reported value in ms is 9.5s (with 10s being the timeout limit):

[image: Example graph]

The queries used for this are as follows:

```
probe_duration_seconds{instance=~"$target"}
```

```
probe_success{instance=~"$target"}
```

I am looking around query operations and the data transformation tab but wasn't able to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use this query:

```
probe_duration_seconds{instance=~"$target"} and probe_success{instance=~"$target"} == 1
```

It will return `probe_duration_seconds` only if `probe_success` with corresponding set of labels had value 1.

More on how logical binary operators work you can read in [official documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators).

Comment: Ooh didn't know they were a thing in promql yet. Thanks a lot for the docs link too.